# Running functions depend on return from previous function Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a test, that checks an element on a page: if element A is presented, test(function) returns A and runs another function A. If element B is presented, test(function) returns B and runs another function B. How can I do it in Python? I think of using dictionary and something like "if" expression, but I hardly imagine, how to do it. Thanks in advance!
I don't have exact code, just something like this :/

```
from Pages import SearchHelper

def finding_pop(browser):
    pop_click = SearchHelper(browser)
    pop_click.go_to_site()
    #element = finding_element_function.get_text()
    return element
    if element =='A':
        #function test_A_click must be run
       else:
        #function test_B_click must be run

def test_A_click(browser):
    pop_click = SearchHelper(browser)
    pop_click.go_to_site()
    logs = pop_click.setting_logs_raw('performance')
    result = pop_click.for_logs(pop_click.log_filter, logs)
    binded = pop_click.searching_params_in_logs_pops(result, 'bind_to')
    ignored = pop_click.searching_params_in_logs_pops(result, 'ignore_to')
    if binded == None and ignored == None:
        handles, url, url1 = pop_click.opened_in_new_window()
        assert handles > 1
        assert url != url1

def test_B_click(browser):
    pop_click = SearchHelper(browser)
    pop_click.go_to_site()
    logs = pop_click.setting_logs_raw('performance')
    result = pop_click.for_logs(pop_click.log_filter, logs)
    binded = pop_click.searching_params_in_logs_pops(result, 'bind_to')
    ignored = pop_click.searching_params_in_logs_pops(result, 'ignore_to')
    if binded == None and ignored == None:
        handles, url, url1 = pop_click.opened_in_current_window()
        print(url, url1)
        assert handles > 1
        assert url != url1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the `return` statement should always be at the end of function, because on the return statement the function ends and no further parts of the function get executed. So in the `finding_pop` fucntion when you write `return element`, that is where your function ends. The `if/else` statements below `return element` are not being executed.

For this perticular scenario **I think you don't need a return statemnet inside your `finding_pop` function** , since you're `finding_pop` function is returning `element` and then you're performing the `if/else` on `element` inside the same the same function.

You can simply change your `finding_pop` function to:

```
def finding_pop(browser):
    pop_click = SearchHelper(browser)
    pop_click.go_to_site()
    
    element = finding_element_function.get_text()
    if element =="A":
        test_A_click(browser)
    elseif element =="B":
        test_B_click(browser)
```

But if you are really in need of a return statement then you need to introduce a separate runner function that will take in the return of `finding_pop` as an input and then perform `if/else` to choose the next function to perform.

So it'll be as:

```
def finding_pop(browser):
    pop_click = SearchHelper(browser)
    pop_click.go_to_site()
    
    element = finding_element_function.get_text() 
    return element

def chose_func_A_or_b(browser):
    element = finding_pop(browser)
    if element == "A":
        test_A_click(browser)
    if element == "B":
        test_B_click(browser)
```

Comment: could you help me a bit more: where should I place my test_A and test_B functions? into if statement?

Comment: Its better if you create the function the function separately and not as a sub-function, so just the way you have written seems good. 
One improvement you could do is is change the order of the functions. they should be written in order[ as:

`finding_pop`
`test_A_click`
`test_B_click`
`chose_func_A_or_b`